# C++ library for dealing with multiple HTTP connections

Tags: c++, winapi, http, curl

I'm looking for a library to deal with multiple simultaneous HTTP connections (pref. on a single thread) to use in C++ in Windows so it can be Win32 API based. This is for a client application that must process a list of requests but keep 4 running at all times until the list is complete.

So far, I have tried cURL (multi interface) which seems to be the most appropriate that I have found but my problem is that I may have a queue of 200 requests but I need to only run 4 of them at a time. This becomes problematic when one request may take 2 seconds and another may take 2 mins as you have to wait on all handles and receive the result of all requests in one block. If anyone knows a way round this it would be very useful.

I have also tried rolling my own using WinHTTP but I need to throttle the requests so they would ideally need to be on a single thread and use callbacks for data which WinHTTP does not do.

The best thing I've found which would solve all my problems is ASIHTTPRequest but unfortunately it's Mac OSX only.

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at boost.asio?  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio.html

Its meant to scale well and has http server examples:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html

Comment: Thanks, I looked at boost.asio and it seemed like I would run into the same issues as libcurl. Is it capable of keeping a constant 4 requests running on a single thread ? i.e. be notified when one is finished fire up another without having to wait for all the requests to complete?

Comment: @JWood, Not done much server programming (just used asio to setup a single connection with a device) Sorry.

Comment: No problem although it's not a server I'm working on, it's a client.

Comment: @JWood: don't understand what you mean by "keeping a constant 4 requests ..." but the whole point of the async programming model is that you launch async. operations and are notified as each one completes. So as soon as one operation completes, you can start another in your handler without having to wait for other outstanding async operations to complete.

Answer (score 3):

Did you tried Boost Asio ?
Is multiplataform and stellar performance, and with nice examples of HTTP.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio.html

Answer (score 0):

Asio is a great library but it's generic, the HTTP examples are just that: examples, there's no support for redirection, authentication and so on.
I know of two libraries built on top of Boost & Asio that support the HTTP protocol: [cpp-netlib](https://github.com/cpp-netlib/cpp-netlib) and [Pion Network Library](http://www.pion.net/projects/pion-network-library) but AFAIK neither directly supports what you want.
All that being said if you're comfortable with using libcurl it should be pretty easy to use the "easy" interface with callbacks and implement the requests queue yourself.

Answer (score 0):

libcurl's multi interface supports exactly what you're asking for.